# Degree of the extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

[image]

Aren't we supposed to know the degree of the field extension to solve this problem? Did I miss something?

Comment: You should know the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F\left[\alpha^3\right]$.

Comment: Is there any hidden info in the question? I don't see it tho

Comment: I don't see anything hidden in the question. Can you find a polynomial $f$ with coefficients in $F(\alpha^3)$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the answer depends on whether $\alpha \in E$, but I suppose you should assume not.

Comment: This is all I've been given. So any suggestion how to start this question? I am totally confused...

Comment: @Travis - why would you assume that? The problem, EXACTLY as stated, has the answer: IF $\alpha \in F$ (not $E$!) then the degree is one, otherwise [...]  Why should you ignore the first part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will depend on whether or not $\alpha \in F$.

Hint: a polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$ is irreducible over a given field if and only if it has no roots.